# Weight ([1..5]) grade in Excel?

Tags: excel

Suppose I have these grades : (I'm using excel 14 , office 2010)

39.55,
28.25,
16.95,
14.53,
13.56,
9.6,
9.6,
9.49,
7.43,
7.35,
3.35,

And I have 5 buckets ( grade weight).

Now , I need to know each grade - to which bucket it belongs:

So , I did this :

1. I calculated : `Max-Min` which is `39.55-3.35` which is `36.2`
2. calculated how many intervals : `36.2 / 5` = 7.24
3. check each grade to which interval it belongs :

So here is the final result : (visually , manually) :

[image]

So you can see that the yellow ones belongs to bucket number 1 ( the yellow interval) , And the blue ones are for bucket number 2...etc...

**Question**

Is there any Excel formula/s  which can get `([range],numBuckets,grade)` and yield the bucket number which it belongs ?

nb - without any help tables. just a single  cell function/s.

Comment: Is it Ok for you a user def function?

Comment: @sancho.s I prefer native built in excel formula/s. (as i want to keep it simple as possible , even without using help tables)....AGain - only if it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the figure

[image]

A3-A13 contain your data. And

A1: =MIN(A3:A13)

A2: =MAX(A3:A13)

B1: 5

B2: =(A2-A1)/B1

B3: =IF(A3=$A$2,$B$1,INT((A3-$A$1)/$B$2)+1)

B4-B13: copy-paste from B3.

I posted it this way for clarity. You can compose all in a single function (be careful with absolute/relative references then).
The only missing point is how to deal with numbers that lay at an exact boundary between bins. That is up to you to define the criterion.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - It just uses the integer part, which gives you steps. Subtracting $A$1 shifts origin, and dividing by $B$2 changes scale, to suit your needs.